# Javascript: `this` and object.method event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, this

I'm trying to take a bunch of `el`'s from an object and attach a method as a click handler, and to pass the clicked `el` to the function. Code looks like this (jQuery):

```
svCatEditor.list.bind('click', svCatEditor.controller($(this)));
```

When I console.log out `$(this)` in `svCatEditor.controller` I get the `window` object. I understand why that happens: http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/

What I don't understand is how to get around it. Do I need to take a completely different approach or is there something simple that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do it the following way:

```
svCatEditor.list.bind('click', function() { svCatEditor.controller($(this)) } );
```

`this` inside the callback function's context refers to the current object that is triggering the event handler. Otherwise in your outside context `this` refers to the window.